# Netbeans : very high memory usage in Yosemite

Tags: php, netbeans, osx-yosemite, netbeans-plugins

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2 (PHP edition) in Yosemite. I've been noticing a high memory usage of the application - for instance, I've checked Activity Monitor now and it was using more than 9GB of RAM! After closing and re-opening it is using less than 1GB.

I'm not doing any big project at the moment; indeed my projects are all small to medium. About the plugins, I use only xdebug, nothing fancy here.

I've noticed that the more time Netbeans is open, more memory it will use. The memory usage seems to increase each time i run or debug the project, so it seems some kind of memory leak.

What could be causing such a ridiculous memory usage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit netbeans.conf (located in "etc" subdir on wherever you installed netbeans), and pass -Xmx parameter, as documented on netbeans.conf itself. Note that if you don't pass this option then by default it will compute a maximum itself as a (big) fraction of your total ram. If you have lots of ram, them this maximum will also be huge, and depending on the jvm version and other parameters, java won't give memory back to the system easily or at all, so you probably want to put a very low bar on it. I leave mine with 1gb of ram and it never complained, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using an Wordpress project. Have you found out if it is some plugin?

I've a pretty standard installation having installed and using the emmet/zen coding. I know that this plugin had been problematic in the past. Do you have it installed?

Best regards.

Comment: I don't have this plugin, actually my installation is pretty standard.

Comment: It must be a memory leak some where because I can see the memory increasing at a steady pace in Activity Monitor. I don't know if this happens when developing in Java.

Comment: Do you have any more info about this problem? I noticed that in windows I don't have this problem with the same netbeans setup and plugins.